# React multiple checkbox with selected values set

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

Hi I am using react form I have issue with multiple checkbox with default value I set some value it working  on uncheck values are not change default values.

code sandbox :https://codesandbox.io/s/mutiple-select-5nmwu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you set `checked` is constant and it never changes. You can update like this.

```
checked={inputs.includes(fruit.id)}
```